# C# dotnet Core project referencing Entity Framework Standard DLL

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to reference dlls in my dotnet core project that are using Entity framework standard, not core.
The problem that i'm running into with dotnet core is that the connection strings that are defined in the appsettings.json are not being read by the referenced dlls, so I get the error:
`Message=No connection string named 'Entities' could be found in the application config file.`

In the dotnet core app I'm able to get the connection string using EF core with:

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
        "Entities": "my connection info", // this works
  },
services.AddDbContext...
```

This all works. The problem that I run into now is that a lot of our legacy code is .net standard, and i'd prefer to just continue to use them as libraries for now.

Where it fails in the referenced libraries is when

```
            using (var context = new Entities()) // here
```

Do I need to modify the entity framework layer in the referenced libraries so that they can accept a connection string as a parameter? That would require a lot of updating very old code.

Comment: Your Entities constructor isn't going to have any context of your .NET Core configuration.

Comment: How about leaving your old code as is and making it a web service you call - I fear that bringing it into a modern project will simply cause more headaches (especially when someone says "let's host this on Linux!)") whereas splitting them and then bringing over (rewriting) anything that presents a performance issue will make a reasonable start to porting/spring cleaning the code